# How to customize the ios keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard

Recently i have seen a ios message application in one of my friends mobile, in that the app has full ios keyboard but the color of the keyboard and the keys have images customized for that app, like very colorful each key have characters with different styles..
how to do that, is there any property for default ios keyboard to customize it or have to design it as a nib and place it there like we do for a calculator..i have searched but many of the results are saying that we can customize the keyboard by having a new nib. But insted of designing new nib for whole keyboard is there any property for ios default keyborad to change its appreance. Thank you

Comment: @ColinE i have seen that question where he wants to display only some letters used for his application, but i want to know is there a way to customize the color and theme for the whole keyboard

Comment: No - that is not possible. You will have to render your own keyboard.